# Culture info and DateTime in a WebApp

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `Silverlight` app and the services part of the application that queries the database, runs the RIA services, etc... is on another machine.
If I am showing some date/time results in the `XAML` views to the users I am getting them from the query. Now the user goes to his Windows machine and from the regional language settings changes the date/time format to for example `"yyyy-MM-dd"` so now they want to the results in that format.

So on my LINQ queries I had written something like this:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

But looks like this isn't looking at client's machine, my guess is that it is looking at the server machine because I had used that in my LINQ queries. So what do you think I should do?  Should I instead call it on `Thread.CurrentThread`?

Comment: You should pass the date to the client directly, then format it on the client.

Comment: I am with @SLaks. I usually live by "convert to/from native format as close to the user as possible."

Comment: would using CurrentThread do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentThread` won't do it either. 
Like @Sklaks mentioned you should do this on the client side.
Since it is a SilverLight application I am assuming you are using some binding in your XAML to show this date, so you should write a simple converter from string to string and do the conversion in there, pass it in your XAML along with your binding. Something like this:

```
DateTime temp;
bool valid= DateTime.TryParse(value, out temp);
if (valid)
{
    result = temp.ToShortDateString();
}
```